# How to stop terminal from automatically executing commands when I open it?

Tags: terminal, macos

When I open terminal, the following automatically shows up:

```
Last login: Thu Dec  8 10:54:34 on ttys001
/Users/user1/.zprofile:14: unmatched "
/Users/user1/.zprofile:14: unmatched "
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:18: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:20: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:22: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:24: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:26: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:28: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:30: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:32: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
/Users/user1/.zshrc:.:34: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
```

How can I stop this from happening? I've tried the following command:
`rm -rf ~/.asdf/`
Here's my .zprofile , but I can't find any missing quotes in here.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv"
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/.zprofile" 13L, 454B
```

Comment: do `vi /Users/user1/.zprofile` and fix it.

Comment: I added the file, but it doesn't appear to have any unmatched quotes @WhiteOwl , do you happen to spot it?

Comment: ... bearing in mind that the problem may be earlier than line 14: this just happens to be where `zsh` realises that some quoting (or bracketing or commenting) does not match expectations. The messages about `asdf` are probably a side-effect of a previous failure: you may come to regret a recursive removal of an innocent bystander.

Comment: How about the missing closing bracket at the end of the last line? That has to balance first, before the quotes balance.

Comment: You will also need to fix your `.zshrc` file where it's looking for files under `/opt/homebrew/opt/`.

Comment: I've fixed the .zshrc file but still can't find the missing "

Comment: Line 5 is repeated -- I don't see why it would do anything different the second time, and it might possibly do something unfortunate.

Comment: Fix it again -- there is a blatant error in the unbalanced ( ... ) on the last line.

Comment: Can you be more specific @Paul_Pedant, I can't see it

Comment: `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv"` has a `$(` but no closing `)`. The parser does not know the process substitution is incomplete, but it does know the eval arg as a whole is incomplete when it runs off the end of the file like a cartoon cat. JUST BALANCE THE BRACKETS.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Nor can I -- I mentioned brackets in *three* previous comments  ;-)